# Is there any way to edit the level.dat as code on MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

Recently I created a mansion on Minecraft pocket edition and blew it up accidentally but I think my level.dat_old still has the mansion. I think it would be the same file type as level.dat when code and I was wondering if there was a way to copy the code over level.dat. I do not own a computer, I just have my android phone.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any tool for minecraft nbt editing that can run on Android. But there are great tools for PC, like for example the Minecraft Universal Editor.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a text editor? I don't know necessarily if there are any available. Otherwise, no, there is no way.